# How to convert oracle stored procedure to simple inserts using sed

Tags: oracle, sed

This is a procedure I want to convert this procedure into simple inserts can anyone help me with this.

```
SET DEFINE OFF
    DECLARE
      null_value CHAR(1) := NULL;
      statement1 CHAR(134);
      statement2 CHAR(78);
      statement3 CHAR(52);
      statement4 CHAR(79);
      statement5 CHAR(143);
      statement6 CHAR(57);
      statement7 CHAR(63);
      statement8 CHAR(67);
    BEGIN
      statement1 := 'INSERT INTO iris_config."PERMISSION" VALUES (:0, :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11, :12, :13, :14, :15, :16, :17, :18, :19)';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement1 USING 'REP_LIEN_ACCOUNT_REPORT_DN', 'REP_LIEN_ACCOUNT_REPORT_DN', 'REPORT_VIEW', 'REP_LIEN_ACCOUNT_REPORT_DN.rpt', 'Distribution Network Lien Account Report', null_value, null_value, null_value, 'Operation', 1, 1, 100, null_value, 4, null_value, '0', 0, 0, null_value, null_value;
      statement2 := 'INSERT INTO iris_config.report VALUES (:0, :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9)';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement2 USING 9240001991, 'REP_LIEN_ACCOUNT_REPORT_DN.rpt', null_value, 'Distribution Network Lien Account Report', 'REP_LIEN_ACCOUNT_REPORT_DN', null_value, '0', 25, null_value, '1';
      statement3 := 'INSERT INTO iris_config.report_group VALUES (:0, :1)';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement3 USING 25, 'Distribution Network';
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Not clear, Please do add more details in your question along with expected output in CODE TAGS. Also do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 In this procedure statement 1 ,statement 2 and statement 3 are 3 database inserts so how can we convert these statement to insert form

Comment: Don't assume we know what "insert form" means. [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input. Also add what you have tried so far. You should probably also add an `awk` tag to your questions since this may involve more than the simple `s/old/new` that sed is the best tool for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to do that using SED. Actually, I don't know how to do it using *any other* text editor. That's not just a simple find/replace operation.

But, if you're unsure of how to do it as far as pure `insert` statement is concerned, then - with the rule that everything that is being part of the `using` clause goes directly into `insert`'s `values` part, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO iris_config.permission
     VALUES ('REP_LIEN_ACCOUNT_REPORT_DN',
             'REP_LIEN_ACCOUNT_REPORT_DN',
             'REPORT_VIEW',
             'REP_LIEN_ACCOUNT_REPORT_DN.rpt',
             'Distribution Network Lien Account Report',
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             'Operation',
             1,
             1,
             100,
             NULL,
             4,
             NULL,
             '0',
             0,
             0,
             NULL,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO iris_config.report
     VALUES (9240001991,
             'REP_LIEN_ACCOUNT_REPORT_DN.rpt',
             NULL,
             'Distribution Network Lien Account Report',
             'REP_LIEN_ACCOUNT_REPORT_DN',
             NULL,
             '0',
             25,
             NULL,
             '1');

INSERT INTO iris_config.report_group
     VALUES (25, 'Distribution Network');
```

Note that such `insert` commands are rather *unsafe*. You should always explicitly name all columns involved. For the last table (`report_group`) it is relatively easy, as it probably reads as

```
INSERT INTO iris_config.report_group (id, name)    --> note ID, NAME here
     VALUES (25, 'Distribution Network');
```

but - what is the 7th `NULL` in the first `insert`? Are you *sure* that it should be `null` and not `13`? Or `'13'` (a string)? True, it requires more typing, but is way better.

Comment: thanx for your answer but how can I automatically convert procedure to inserts

Comment: You're welcome. As I said: "I don't know how to do it using any other text editor. That's not just a simple find/replace operation." From my point of view, it would take some *serious* programming.